# Do I always need to join threads?

Tags: c++11

When looking for examples of threading in c++11, every example joins the threads.

**Do I need to join the threads?**

**More info**
I am creating the threads in a *'game loop'* so it is unlikely that the program will exit before the thread has finished executing. After the thread function has finished execution can I just set an atomic flag like `done`?

**For example**
Please take this example here Foo is only drawn if it has loaded:

```
struct Foo {
   std::atomic<bool> isLoaded = false;
   void load() {
        std::thread( [&isLoaded] () {
            doSomethingExpensive();
            isLoaded = true;
        });
    }
    void draw() {
        if ( !isLoaded ) { return; }
    }
}

void App::setup() {
    for ( int i = 0; i<100; ++i ) {
        std::shared_ptr<Foo> fooPtr;
        fooPtr->load();
        fooPtrs.push_back( fooPtr );
    }
}

void App::loop() {
    for ( auto &foo : fooPtrs ) {
        fooPtrs->draw();
    }
}
```

Is this suitable / good practise / a good strategy?

Comment: Scott Meyers talks a bit about this in his [Going Native 2013 talk](http://channel9.msdn.com/Events/GoingNative/2013/An-Effective-Cpp11-14-Sampler) for anyone interested. I can see there's already at least one correct answer: You should never allow joinable threads to be destroyed.

Answer (score 2):

This will cause your program to exit. When a thread goes out of scope, it will cause program termination if it hasn't been joined or detached. You could detach the thread, but then you have no access to it. The better solution would be to make the thread a member of the class so that it doesn't go out of scope after you create it. So long as you make sure it's cleaned up properly, in that case joining is not required.